# C++/CLI Enabling textbox on form 1 when clicking button on form 2

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm currently working on a visual c++ program where I have multiple textboxes on my first form, all of which require a number. What these are doing is asking for a number to be entered (amount of specific expense). For some of my expenses they involve multiple smaller expenses to calculate the expense. To accomplish that I have the corresponding textbox disabled at first, and have a button next to each disabled textbox. When the user clicks the button next to each textbox it brings up a separate form (while still keeping the main form open) that prompts the user to enter all of the smaller expenses that are totaled on a button click on that form. Then once they click the button to total the expenses on the form a return button appears that when clicked closes the form and leaves only the main expense form open. My predicament is I need to send back the total calculated value for the specific expense, place it in the corresponding textbox on the main expense form, as well as enabled that textbox. I believe I have the method down for returning the value to the main expense form, then assigning it to the textbox, but I'm not quite sure how to enable the textbox once the user clicks the button to return to the main expense form on the smaller pop-up expense form. Any tips or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Side note of curiosity: Would I even need to enable the textbox on the main expense form in order to place the returned value into it, then use the value in a calculation that involves all the expenses on the main expense form?

```
//ExpensesForm.h
#pragma once
#include "MiscExpensesCalculateForm.h"

    namespace Project1 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for ExpensesForm
/// </summary>
public ref class ExpensesForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

public:
    ExpensesForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~ExpensesForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  maskedTextBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  maskedTextBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  maskedTextBox3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  maskedTextBox4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  maskedTextBox5;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  maskedTextBox6;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  maskedTextBox7;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label8;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  maskedTextBox8;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  maskedTextBox9;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label9;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label10;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label11;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button5;
public: System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox^  misctotaltextbox;

private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label12;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label13;
protected:

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(ExpensesForm::typeid));
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->maskedTextBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->maskedTextBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->maskedTextBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->maskedTextBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->maskedTextBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->maskedTextBox6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->maskedTextBox7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->label8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->button3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->maskedTextBox8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->button4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->maskedTextBox9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->label9 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label10 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label11 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->button5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->misctotaltextbox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskedTextBox());
        this->label12 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->label13 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 86);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(74, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->label1->Text = L"Cell Phone Bill";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this->label2->AutoSize = true;
        this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 230);
        this->label2->Name = L"label2";
        this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(111, 13);
        this->label2->TabIndex = 1;
        this->label2->Text = L"Doctors Appointments";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this->label3->AutoSize = true;
        this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 124);
        this->label3->Name = L"label3";
        this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(73, 13);
        this->label3->TabIndex = 2;
        this->label3->Text = L"Car Insurance";
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this->label4->AutoSize = true;
        this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 195);
        this->label4->Name = L"label4";
        this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(91, 13);
        this->label4->TabIndex = 3;
        this->label4->Text = L"Therapy Sessions";
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        this->label5->AutoSize = true;
        this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 160);
        this->label5->Name = L"label5";
        this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(88, 13);
        this->label5->TabIndex = 4;
        this->label5->Text = L"Health Insurance";
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        this->label6->AutoSize = true;
        this->label6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 343);
        this->label6->Name = L"label6";
        this->label6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(30, 13);
        this->label6->TabIndex = 5;
        this->label6->Text = L"Rent";
        // 
        // maskedTextBox1
        // 
        this->maskedTextBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 83);
        this->maskedTextBox1->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->maskedTextBox1->Name = L"maskedTextBox1";
        this->maskedTextBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->maskedTextBox1->TabIndex = 6;
        // 
        // maskedTextBox2
        // 
        this->maskedTextBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 121);
        this->maskedTextBox2->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->maskedTextBox2->Name = L"maskedTextBox2";
        this->maskedTextBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->maskedTextBox2->TabIndex = 7;
        // 
        // maskedTextBox3
        // 
        this->maskedTextBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 157);
        this->maskedTextBox3->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->maskedTextBox3->Name = L"maskedTextBox3";
        this->maskedTextBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->maskedTextBox3->TabIndex = 8;
        // 
        // maskedTextBox4
        // 
        this->maskedTextBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 192);
        this->maskedTextBox4->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->maskedTextBox4->Name = L"maskedTextBox4";
        this->maskedTextBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->maskedTextBox4->TabIndex = 9;
        // 
        // maskedTextBox5
        // 
        this->maskedTextBox5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 227);
        this->maskedTextBox5->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->maskedTextBox5->Name = L"maskedTextBox5";
        this->maskedTextBox5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->maskedTextBox5->TabIndex = 10;
        // 
        // maskedTextBox6
        // 
        this->maskedTextBox6->Enabled = false;
        this->maskedTextBox6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 340);
        this->maskedTextBox6->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->maskedTextBox6->Name = L"maskedTextBox6";
        this->maskedTextBox6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->maskedTextBox6->TabIndex = 11;
        // 
        // label7
        // 
        this->label7->AutoSize = true;
        this->label7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 379);
        this->label7->Name = L"label7";
        this->label7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(44, 13);
        this->label7->TabIndex = 12;
        this->label7->Text = L"Grocery";
        // 
        // maskedTextBox7
        // 
        this->maskedTextBox7->Enabled = false;
        this->maskedTextBox7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 376);
        this->maskedTextBox7->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->maskedTextBox7->Name = L"maskedTextBox7";
        this->maskedTextBox7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->maskedTextBox7->TabIndex = 13;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"button1.BackgroundImage")));
        this->button1->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Center;
        this->button1->FlatAppearance->BorderSize = 0;
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(127, 373);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 25);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 14;
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this->button2->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"button2.BackgroundImage")));
        this->button2->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Center;
        this->button2->FlatAppearance->BorderSize = 0;
        this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(127, 337);
        this->button2->Name = L"button2";
        this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 25);
        this->button2->TabIndex = 15;
        this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // label8
        // 
        this->label8->AutoSize = true;
        this->label8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 306);
        this->label8->Name = L"label8";
        this->label8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(61, 13);
        this->label8->TabIndex = 16;
        this->label8->Text = L"Gas/Travel";
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this->button3->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"button3.BackgroundImage")));
        this->button3->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Center;
        this->button3->FlatAppearance->BorderSize = 0;
        this->button3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(127, 300);
        this->button3->Name = L"button3";
        this->button3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 25);
        this->button3->TabIndex = 18;
        this->button3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // maskedTextBox8
        // 
        this->maskedTextBox8->Enabled = false;
        this->maskedTextBox8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 303);
        this->maskedTextBox8->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->maskedTextBox8->Name = L"maskedTextBox8";
        this->maskedTextBox8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->maskedTextBox8->TabIndex = 17;
        // 
        // button4
        // 
        this->button4->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"button4.BackgroundImage")));
        this->button4->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Center;
        this->button4->FlatAppearance->BorderSize = 0;
        this->button4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(127, 259);
        this->button4->Name = L"button4";
        this->button4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 25);
        this->button4->TabIndex = 20;
        this->button4->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // maskedTextBox9
        // 
        this->maskedTextBox9->Enabled = false;
        this->maskedTextBox9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 262);
        this->maskedTextBox9->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->maskedTextBox9->Name = L"maskedTextBox9";
        this->maskedTextBox9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->maskedTextBox9->TabIndex = 19;
        this->maskedTextBox9->MaskInputRejected += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MaskInputRejectedEventHandler(this, &ExpensesForm::maskedTextBox9_MaskInputRejected);
        // 
        // label9
        // 
        this->label9->AutoSize = true;
        this->label9->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 265);
        this->label9->Name = L"label9";
        this->label9->Size = System::Drawing::Size(64, 13);
        this->label9->TabIndex = 21;
        this->label9->Text = L"Medications";
        // 
        // label10
        // 
        this->label10->AutoSize = true;
        this->label10->Location = System::Drawing::Point(416, 50);
        this->label10->Name = L"label10";
        this->label10->Size = System::Drawing::Size(80, 13);
        this->label10->TabIndex = 22;
        this->label10->Text = L"The Run-Down";
        // 
        // label11
        // 
        this->label11->AutoSize = true;
        this->label11->Location = System::Drawing::Point(345, 81);
        this->label11->Name = L"label11";
        this->label11->Size = System::Drawing::Size(228, 351);
        this->label11->TabIndex = 23;
        this->label11->Text = resources->GetString(L"label11.Text");
        // 
        // button5
        // 
        this->button5->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"button5.BackgroundImage")));
        this->button5->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Center;
        this->button5->FlatAppearance->BorderSize = 0;
        this->button5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(127, 408);
        this->button5->Name = L"button5";
        this->button5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 25);
        this->button5->TabIndex = 26;
        this->button5->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button5->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &ExpensesForm::button5_Click);
        // 
        // misctotaltextbox
        // 
        this->misctotaltextbox->Enabled = false;
        this->misctotaltextbox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(158, 411);
        this->misctotaltextbox->Mask = L"000.00";
        this->misctotaltextbox->Name = L"misctotaltextbox";
        this->misctotaltextbox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
        this->misctotaltextbox->TabIndex = 25;
        // 
        // label12
        // 
        this->label12->AutoSize = true;
        this->label12->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 414);
        this->label12->Name = L"label12";
        this->label12->Size = System::Drawing::Size(32, 13);
        this->label12->TabIndex = 24;
        this->label12->Text = L"Misc.";
        // 
        // label13
        // 
        this->label13->AutoSize = true;
        this->label13->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
            static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
        this->label13->Location = System::Drawing::Point(263, 12);
        this->label13->Name = L"label13";
        this->label13->Size = System::Drawing::Size(95, 24);
        this->label13->TabIndex = 27;
        this->label13->Text = L"Expenses";
        // 
        // ExpensesForm
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(637, 499);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label13);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->misctotaltextbox);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label12);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label11);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label10);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label9);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->maskedTextBox9);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->maskedTextBox8);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label8);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->maskedTextBox7);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label7);
        this->Controls->Add(this->maskedTextBox6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->maskedTextBox5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->maskedTextBox4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->maskedTextBox3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->maskedTextBox2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->maskedTextBox1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label6);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Name = L"ExpensesForm";
        this->Text = L"Budget Buddy - Expenses";
        this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &ExpensesForm::ExpensesForm_Load);
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
    #pragma endregion
        private: System::Void maskedTextBox9_MaskInputRejected(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MaskInputRejectedEventArgs^  e) {
}
    private: System::Void button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         MiscExpensesCalculateForm^ mecf = gcnew MiscExpensesCalculateForm();
         mecf->ShowDialog();
 }

   private: System::Void ExpensesForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
};
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472653/enable-a-button-after-closing-a-form) post and it's exactly what I need to do, but I just don't know where to put the code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what that means, but I'll see about including the code in a second to give you an idea of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

What is usually done (see types like `FileDialog`) is to put some public properties in the modal form class (here, `MiscExpensesCalculateForm`) and simply set them before calling `ShowDialog` and read them afterwards).

```
private: System::Void button5_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    MiscExpensesCalculateForm^ mecf = gcnew MiscExpensesCalculateForm();
    mecf->SomeInputData = blahblah;
    DialogResult dr = mecf->ShowDialog();
    if(dr == DialogResult.OK) {
        textBoxResult->Text = mecf->MyResultData;
        textBoxResult->Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and I apologize for the delay in response, but I ultimately decided to use VB.net instead since it's easier to code in my opinion.